# Manipulate Equation to get Complicated Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $$a/x+b/y+c/z=1/143$$ for real numbers $a, b,$ and $c$. What is:
$$abc(x/a+y/b+z/c-143)/((11a-x/13)(11b-y/13)(11c-x/13))\:?$$

Comment: where did you get this one?

Comment: A friend asked me this question last month. She said there's a nice way to do, but I'm not so sure, so I'm asking you guys.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

With

$\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}+\frac{c}{z}=\frac{1}{143}$  (I)

$\frac{1}{xbc}+\frac{1}{yac}+\frac{1}{zab}=\frac{1}{143abc}$ (II)

Expand the expression and do some algebra operation

$\frac{abc(\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}−143)}{(11a−\frac{x}{13})(11b−\frac{y}{13})(11c−\frac{z}{13})}$

=$\frac{(xbc+yac+zab-143abc)13^3}{(143a-x)(143b-y)(143c-z)}$

=$\frac{(xbc+yac+zab-143abc)13^3}{143^3abc-143^2(xbc+yac+zab)+143(ayz+bxz+cxy)-xyz}$

=$\frac{(xbc+yac+zab-143abc)13^3}{143^3abc-143^2(xbc+yac+zab)+143xyz(\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}+\frac{c}{z})-xyz}$  (III)

Compare  (III) with (I), (II), you will get the answer.

> -$\frac{13}{11}$